# Determine current print job color using C#

Tags: c#, printing, colors

Before coming to SO for an answer I've spent the last 2 or 3 days on Google trying different question forms to try and get this to work.

I need to get the color setting of the current print job to determine how many color or grayscale prints a user has performed. However every single color property I've tried to access (through ManagementObjectSearcher, ""Watcher, and the built-in printer classes of C#) always return color, never grayscale.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, since I've come to a stop on making progress with solutions. Thanks. Below is the code I have (keep in mind it's my prototyping code so there might be many issues apart from what I'm asking. Please only provide suggestions WITH your answer to my question).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Printing;
using System.Management;
using System.Management.Instrumentation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;

using System.Diagnostics;

namespace PrintPlus {
    public partial class PrintPlus : Form {

    #region Objects
    // Mgmt 
    ManagementEventWatcher watcher;
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher;

    // Thread
    Thread jobCheck;

    // Printer Objects
    PrintQueue printQ;
    PrintJobInfoCollection printJobCollection;

    // Timer
    private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timeLogged;

    #endregion

    #region Paths And Names

    string localMachineName;

    #endregion

    #region Costs

    private decimal timeCost;
    private decimal printCost;

    #endregion

    #region Print Variables

    private int color;

    private bool jobIsProcessing;

    private int numberOfPrints;
    private int colorPrints;
    private int greyScalePrints;

    private int printJobCount;

    #endregion

    #region Time Variables

    private float tSecs;
    private float tMins;
    private float tHrs;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public PrintPlus() {
        InitializeComponent();
        initObjects();

        /* searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob");

        watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM  __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 0.01 WHERE TargetInstance ISA \"Win32_PrintJob\"");
        watcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(getColorSetting);
        watcher.Start();

        localMachineName = Environment.MachineName;*/
    }

    #endregion

    #region Initializers

    private void initObjects() {
        initPrinterObjects();
        initTimer();
    }

    private void initPrinterObjects() {
        LocalPrintServer lps = new LocalPrintServer();
        printQ = new PrintQueue(lps, lps.DefaultPrintQueue.Name);
    }

    private void initTimer() {
        timeLogged = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timeLogged.Interval = 1000;
        timeLogged.Tick += new EventHandler(onTick);
        timeLogged.Start();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Delegates

    private void onTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        updateTime();
        updateInfo();
    }

    private void onMove(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Location = initialPosition;
    }

    private void onLoseFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.MinimizeBox = true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Updates

    private void updateInfo() {
        printJobCount = printQ.GetPrintJobInfoCollection().Count<PrintSystemJobInfo>();

        if (printJobCount >= 1 && !jobIsProcessing) {
            jobIsProcessing = true;
            jobCheck = new Thread(new ThreadStart(processJobs));
            jobCheck.Start();
        }

        numberOfPrints = (colorPrints + greyScalePrints);

        timeCostLbl.Text = "Time: $" + timeCost.ToString();
        printCostLbl.Text = "Print: $" + printCost.ToString();
        totalCostLbl.Text = "Total: $" + (timeCost + printCost).ToString();
        printedPagesLbl.Text = "Printed Pages: " + numberOfPrints.ToString() + " Colour: " + colorPrints.ToString() + " B&W: " + greyScalePrints.ToString();
   }

    private void updateTime() {
        tSecs += timeLogged.Interval / 1000;

        if (tSecs == 60) {
            timeCost += FEES.COST_PER_MIN;
            tMins += 1;
            if (tMins == 60) {
                tHrs += 1;
            }
            tSecs = 0;
        }
        int i = 0;

        String hrs = ((tHrs >= 10) ? tHrs.ToString() : i + tHrs.ToString());
        String mins = ((tMins >= 10) ? tMins.ToString() : i + tMins.ToString());
        String secs = ((tSecs >= 10) ? tSecs.ToString() : i + tSecs.ToString());

        this.timeElapsedLbl.Text = "Time Logged: " + hrs + " : " + mins + " : " + secs;
    }

    public void processJobs() {
        LocalPrintServer lps = new LocalPrintServer();
        PrintQueue printQ = new PrintQueue(lps, lps.DefaultPrintQueue.Name);
        PrintJobInfoCollection printJobCollection = printQ.GetPrintJobInfoCollection();
        PrintSystemJobInfo[] jobArray = printJobCollection.ToArray<PrintSystemJobInfo>();

        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob");
        ManagementObjectCollection searchCollection = searcher.Get();

        foreach (ManagementObject job in searchCollection) {
            foreach (PropertyData prop in job.Properties) {
                Debug.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);
            }
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < jobArray.Length; ++i) {
                if (jobArray[i].PositionInPrintQueue == 1) {
                    while (jobArray[i].JobStatus != PrintJobStatus.Deleted) {
                        jobArray[i].Refresh();
                    }
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(printQ.CurrentJobSettings.CurrentPrintTicket.OutputColor.Value);

                /*if (jobArray[i].PropertiesCollection. == "Color") {
                    colorPrints += jobArray[i].NumberOfPagesPrinted;
                }
                else if (jobArray[i].PropertiesCollection["Color"].ToString() == "Monochrome") {
                    greyScalePrints += jobArray[i].NumberOfPagesPrinted;
                }*/
            }
        }
        finally {
            jobIsProcessing = false;
            lps.Dispose();
            printQ.Dispose();
            printJobCollection.Dispose();
            jobCheck.Abort();
        }
    }

    private void getPrintWatcher(int jobID) {

    }

    private void getColorSetting(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
       /* foreach (PropertyData data in e.NewEvent.Properties) {
            ManagementBaseObject mbo = data.Value as ManagementBaseObject;

            if (mbo.Properties["Color"].Value == "Color") {
                color = COLOR_VALUES.COLOR;
            }
            else if (mbo.Properties["Color"].Value == "Monochrome") {
                color = COLOR_VALUES.MONO;
            }
        }*/
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are experiencing is because the printer is capable of printing in color and black and white. When you print a black letter text document via a color printer the WIN32_PrintJob will still say that the document is a color document UNLESS you explicitly tell the printer to print in black and white via the local machine's 'printer preferences' dialog.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I figured it might be something like that. Is there any way I can determine the nature of the printed page when it comes to color/monochrome?

Comment: "...explicitly tell the printer to print in black and white via the local machine's 'printer preferences' dialog." <-- I believe I've done this. I've tried both grayscale option and "true black" and both times it returns color.

Comment: I tested this using some of your sample code and when I switched my printer settings to use 'black and white' over 'color' the WIN32_PrintJob color property was set to monochrome. As for determining the nature of the printed page, that might require bypassing the WIN API and communicating directly with the printer hardware.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for another reply. I've gone and tested what you've done and it still registers as color for me, in both grayscale and black ink only. Here is an imgur link showing what I mean: http://imgur.com/nK8nKhV

Also, would you happen to have any good resources to direct my efforts for speaking to the printer head on?

Comment: I'm not sure why the color property was not reflected as monochrome. There might be something off with the printer driver or how Windows communicates with it internally.

Answer (score 0):

Color counter of each printer maker and model works differently. Your best bet would be before processing the printing, go through the printing material and determine the colour pages and black pages. If not you will have to relay on the machine counter which only available for Multi functional printers, you can get this information through SNMP.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time to weigh out how to get the real value of the defined color printing and discovered that Win32_PrintJob provides this information in this way:

```
public static bool PausePrintJob(string printerName, int printJobID)
{
    bool isActionPerformed = false;
    string searchQuery = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob";
    ManagementObjectSearcher searchPrintJobs = new ManagementObjectSearcher(searchQuery);
    ManagementObjectCollection prntJobCollection = searchPrintJobs.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject prntJob in prntJobCollection)
    {
        System.String jobName = prntJob.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();

        //Job name would be of the format [Printer name], [Job ID]
        char[] splitArr = new char[1];
        splitArr[0] = Convert.ToChar(",");
        string prnterName = jobName.Split(splitArr)[0];
        int prntJobID = Convert.ToInt32(jobName.Split(splitArr)[1]);
        string documentName = prntJob.Properties["Document"].Value.ToString();

        if (String.Compare(prnterName, printerName, true) == 0)
        {
            if (prntJobID == printJobID)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("PAGINAS : " + prntJob.Properties["TotalPages"].Value.ToString() + documentName + " " + prntJobID);
                prntJob.InvokeMethod("Pause", null);
                MessageBox.Show(prntJob.Properties["Color"].Value.ToString());

                //prntJob.InvokeMethod("Resume", null);
                isActionPerformed = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isActionPerformed;
}
```